# Changing minDate option in DatePicker not working given the existing answers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm following the existing answers for the problem, as well as the API, here's what I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/aLgwcg99/

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
$("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', new Date());

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker('options', 'minDate', new Date());
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input id="datepicker" type="text">
<button id="add_30">Set minDate</button>
```

As you can see by the console, it doesn't work, and gives a very generic error. What am I doing wrong? I want to set the minDate option dynamically, after initializing, using a Date object as a parameter.

Comment: It's `option` singular, not `options` plural. So `.datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `option` instead of `options`.

So this will be good:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker('option', 'minDate', '-3');
```

Check the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aLgwcg99/1/)**

Comment: Well, that's a whole hour of work time wasted! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Essentially it's a typo, and the question should be closed as off-topic. No need to farm rep from it.